# An example of using Data.Map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hashtable

I'm new in Haskell and I need to define an empty Data.map and assigning a "list of integers" (e.g. [1,2,3]) to its keys by using insert function and also updating the values. Then looking up the key values.

What I have tried so far is :

```
import qualified Data.Map

foo num =
    let
        my_map  = Data.Map.empty

        new_map = bar my_map  num 1

    in
        Data.Map.lookup 1 new_map


bar my_map num c =
    if c > num then my_map
    else
        Data.Map.insert  c  [c] my_map
        bar my_map  num  c+1
```

This code doesn't work.

Could you have a simple example please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Most of the functionality you're looking for is available directly as functions in `Data.Map`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I thought it's clear from the OP's post what s/he has tried.

Comment: @talonx The question was edited 3 days after I wrote my comment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

People normally import the `Data.Map` module with this boilerplate:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

The idea is that since many of the names in the module clash with the `Prelude` and other modules, you want to use them as qualified names—but not for the `Map` type itself.  And the `as Map` bit in the second line saves you from having to type as much—you just say `Map.map`, `Map.empty`, etc.

Now, the easiest and most common way of constructing a map is to use the `fromList` function in the module.  This constructs a `Map` from a list of key/value pairs: `Map.fromList :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> Map k v`.  To construct this list of key/value pairs you can use the full power of Haskell's list processing functions, like in this example:

```
myMap :: Integer -> Map Integer [Integer]
myMap n = Map.fromList (map makePair [1..n])
    where makePair x = (x, [x])
```

Example output in GHCI:

```
>>> myMap 3
fromList [(1,[1]),(2,[2]),(3,[3])]
```

Note that the `Map` type even prints itself as a `fromList` call that would reconstruct it.  Why?  Because again, this function really is the most common way to build a `Map`.

In contrast, what you're doing in your code is you're trying to write an imperative-style loop that successively augments an initial empty map with entries one at a time.  The Haskell equivalent of loops is list functions.  In my version I used the following:

1. `[1..n]`—generate a list of the integers from `1` up to `n`.
2. `map`—apply a function to each element of the list.
3. `Map.fromList`—build a `Map` from a list of key/value pairs.

And to further demonstrate that point, if you look at [the source code for `Map.fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0/docs/src/Data-Map-Base.html#fromList), it's actually defined using a list fold function.

My advise to you: study lists and the [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html) module first before you tackle `Map`.  In particular:

1. Learn what functions are available there and what to do.
2. Study the `foldr` function from that module—how to use it, and how to write it.
3. Learn how to write your own versions of `map`, `filter` and `find` in terms of `foldr`.

Comment: Woow! This is great! Now, I know both using Data.Map in Haskell and this optimized way for doing what I wanted to do.

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea about what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a small program to demonstrate this functionality:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as M

main = do
    let emptyMap = M.empty
        mapWithKeys = M.insert 5 "Four" emptyMap
        mapWithKeys' = M.insert 5 "Five" mapWithKeys
    putStrLn $ mapWithKeys' M.! 5
```

The program will insert "Four" with the key 5, then update the value to "Five", and finally look it up and print it.

Comment: You don't need a `let` for each binding. Just one, with appropriate indentation, is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `Data.Map` in base.

While this package does export `empty` which creates a map, it is easier to build one with

`myMap = Data.Map.fromList [(1,"hello"), (3,"goodbye")]`

`fromList` takes a list of (key,value) tuples, and creates a map. This is if you know all the key-value pairs you need at the time of construction.

You can use `(!)` or `Data.Map.lookup` to access elements

Comment: Why is it better to use `fromList` than `empty`?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I thought fromList did something a little smarter, but it just strings together a bunch of inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suggests you have a few misunderstandings.

```
import qualified Data.Map

foo num =
    let
        my_map  = Data.Map.empty

        new_map = bar my_map  num 1

    in
        Data.Map.lookup 1 map
```

I see you use the `map` variable but probably meant `new_map`.  Since Haskell defines a function named `map`, the compiler would tell you a type error.  Purely for readability, reducing white space and adding type signatures helps a lot.

```
-- foo takes an `Int` and produces a Maybe [Int].
foo :: Int -> Maybe [Int]
foo num =
    let my_map  = Data.Map.empty
        new_map = bar my_map  num 1
    in Data.Map.lookup 1 new_map
```

Now let's see `bar`:

```
bar my_map num c =
    if c > num then my_map
    else
        Data.Map.insert  c  [c] my_map
        bar my_map  num  c+1
```

There are a few problems here:

- The `then` and `else` keywords should be in the same column
- Your `c+1` should have parentheses
- You need to use a `let` binding - this is not a mutable map, so by inserting you are actually creating a new map with the new value.

So:

```
bar :: Map Int [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Map Int [Int]
bar my_map num c =
    if c > num
      then my_map
      else let my_new_map = Data.Map.insert  c  [c] my_map
           in bar my_new_map  num  (c+1)
```

Comment: About new_map, yes, you are right. It was a misspelling that I fixed it now. You are passing a list [1] as the second argument to function "bar", and in the "bar", you are comparing a list to a num (c > num) , how is it possible? What I intended to have about the Data.Map was to have type of Key as "integer", and type of Value as "list of integer". Thank you.

Comment: Right, `foo` was passing `[Int]` while `bar` was only accepting `Int` - my mistake.  It wasn't that `bar` was comparing `Int` to `[Int]` (notice the type was always accepting just `Int`), but I mis-used `bar` in `foo`.  I'm made a quick adjustment to `foo` to make it pass just `Int` and not a singleton list of `Int`s.